# Как получить из многомерного массива два значения в массив? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как получить из многомерного массива два значения в массив? чтобы потом можно было к каждому из них обращаться Laravel

Сейчас я получаю ларавелевским хелпером только одно значение дату.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой код

```html
public function getApiHolidays()
    {
        $apiDate = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/russian__ru%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyC8khrJO57yl4szjLOuyQrlW7R_CKgwaH0'),1);
        $holidayDates = Arr::pluck($apiDate['items'], 'start.date');



        $array = array_filter($holidayDates, function($var){
            return substr($var, 0, 4) === date("Y");
        });

        dd($apiDate, $array, $holidayDates);
        
        return $array;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Третим аргуметом метод Arr::pluck принимает ключ значения, можно в качестве ключа использовать дату, а в качестве значения - название.

```
public function getApiHolidays()
{
    $apiDate = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/russian__ru%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyC8khrJO57yl4szjLOuyQrlW7R_CKgwaH0'), 1);

    $holidayDates = Arr::pluck($apiDate['items'], 'summary', 'start.date');

    $array = Arr::where($holidayDates, function ($title, $date) {
        return substr($date, 0, 4) === date("Y");
    });

    return $array;
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [2019-01-01] => Новый Год
    [2019-01-02] => Новогодние каникулы
    [2019-01-03] => Новогодние каникулы
    ...
)
```

Или можно просто перебрать массив и составить нужный:

```
public function getApiHolidays()
{
    $result = [];
    $apiDate = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/russian__ru%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyC8khrJO57yl4szjLOuyQrlW7R_CKgwaH0'), 1);

    foreach ($apiDate['items'] as $item) {

        if (substr($item['start']['date'], 0, 4) !== date('Y')) {
            continue;
        }

        $result[] = [
            $item['start']['date'],
            $item['summary']
        ];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-01
            [1] => Новый Год
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-02
            [1] => Новогодние каникулы
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-01-03
            [1] => Новогодние каникулы
        )
     ....
)
```